# Windows 7: Change pinned Command Prompt icon?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, command-line

How can I change the icon of a Command Prompt icon that's pinned to my Windows 7 taskbar?

I've gone into its properties, selected "Change icon", browsed to the new icon, and pressed "OK".  The system acts as Windows always has in that situation, but the icon does not change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try making a shortcut to CMD on the desktop, change the icon there and pin it afterwards...

i usually pres Windows+R and type CMD followed by Return to get the.
then if I need administrative access from CMD I use sudo for windows

http://sudown.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Agreed. I was about to post the same answer. I have tested it.